# Pandas Grouper with multiple categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, data-analysis

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
          Cat1  Cat2    Cat3    Amount  Offset  Adjust
2018-01-01   A     X       P    12.0    15.0    20.0
2018-01-02   B     Z       Q    42.0    43.0    67.0
2018-01-03   C     Y       R    80.0    15.0    40.0
2018-01-04   B     Z       R    15.0    55.0    30.0
2018-01-05   A     X       P    11.0    20.0    22.0
2018-01-06   A     Z       Q    13.0    10.0    30.0
```

What I am trying to achieve:

1. Resample the TS at weekly level **but** also
2. Groupby `Cat1` and `Cat2`
3. Keep the first item for the remaining categorical columns
4. Sum up the aggregated values for the numerical columns

The final dataframe will look like this:

```
2018-01-06   A  X   P  23.0  35.0  42.0
                Z   Q  13.0  10.0  30.0
             B  Z   Q  57.0  98.0  107.0
             ...
```

Comment: @jezrael can you suggest something please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Cat1": {"2018-01-01": "A", "2018-01-02": "B", "2018-01-03": "C", "2018-01-04": "B", "2018-01-05": "A", "2018-01-06": "A"},
        "Cat2": {"2018-01-01": "X", "2018-01-02": "Z", "2018-01-03": "Y", "2018-01-04": "Z", "2018-01-05": "X", "2018-01-06": "Z"},
        "Cat3": {"2018-01-01": "P", "2018-01-02": "Q", "2018-01-03": "R", "2018-01-04": "R", "2018-01-05": "P", "2018-01-06": "Q"},
        "Amount": {"2018-01-01": 12.0, "2018-01-02": 42.0, "2018-01-03": 80.0, "2018-01-04": 15.0, "2018-01-05": 11.0, "2018-01-06": 13.0},
        "Offset": {"2018-01-01": 15.0, "2018-01-02": 43.0, "2018-01-03": 15.0, "2018-01-04": 55.0, "2018-01-05": 20.0, "2018-01-06": 10.0},
        "Adjust": {"2018-01-01": 20.0, "2018-01-02": 67.0, "2018-01-03": 40.0, "2018-01-04": 30.0, "2018-01-05": 22.0, "2018-01-06": 30.0},
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Setup
df = df.reset_index()
df["index"] = pd.to_datetime(df["index"], format="%Y-%m-%d")

# Find target week day and update other values
df.loc[df["index"].dt.dayofweek != 5, "index"] = pd.NA
df["index"] = df["index"].fillna(method="bfill")

# Group values
df = df.groupby(["index", "Cat1", "Cat2"]).agg(
    {"Cat3": lambda x: x, "Amount": sum, "Offset": sum, "Adjust": sum}
)
df["Cat3"] = df["Cat3"].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

So that:

```py
print(df)
# Output
                     Cat3  Amount  Offset  Adjust
index      Cat1 Cat2
2018-01-06 A    X       P    23.0    35.0    42.0
                Z       Q    13.0    10.0    30.0
           B    Z       Q    57.0    98.0    97.0
           C    Y       R    80.0    15.0    40.0
```